# drupal - default select box - normal or ajax auto-suggest

Tags: ajax, drupal, select

In Drupal 6 - Our default select box is the "Ajax - autosuggest" variation. This shows up in Location and Views modules amoung other places.

Is there a place where we can set this to the regular select-dropdown type of select box?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a module for that? You can turn it off by development.